# 'RoutingSlipCompleted' does not contain a definition for 'GetVariable'

Tags: .net-core, masstransit, consumer, routing-slip, masstransit-courier

after using massTransit (8.0.8) I got following error :

> 'RoutingSlipCompleted' does not contain a definition for 'GetVariable'
> and the best extension method overload
> 'RoutingSlipEventExtensions.GetVariable(ConsumeContext,
> string, Guid)' requires a receiver of type
> 'ConsumeContext'
> here is my code:

```
using MassTransit;
using MassTransit.Courier.Contracts;
using MassTransit.Courier;

public class CheckInventoriesConsumer: IConsumer<ICheckInventoryRequest>
        , IConsumer<RoutingSlipCompleted>
        , IConsumer<RoutingSlipFaulted>
    {
        private readonly IEndpointNameFormatter _formatter;
        public CheckInventoriesConsumer(IEndpointNameFormatter formatter)
        {
            _formatter = formatter;
        }
        public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<ICheckInventoryRequest> context)
        {
            var routingSlip =  CreateRoutingSlip(context);
             await context.Execute(routingSlip);
        }
        private RoutingSlip CreateRoutingSlip(ConsumeContext<ICheckInventoryRequest> context)
        { // lot of code here
         }
        public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<RoutingSlipCompleted> context)
        {
           // error is here
            context.Message.GetVariable<Guid>(nameof(ConsumeContext.RequestId));

            throw new NotImplementedException();
         }
    }
```

It is not going to find `GetVariable` method from `MassTransit.Courier` and I encounter with this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've already found based upon your comments:

```cs
context.GetVariable<Guid>(nameof(ConsumeContext.RequestId));
```

Is the right solution.

MassTransit Version 8 has more extensive serialization support, and the `SerializationContext` (from `ConsumeContext`) is needed to properly deserialize the variable from the routing slip event.